# creating a list of lists for a given number of iterations in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, iteration

I am working on the below piece of code where I have a list of dates (date_index) and another list (date_unique) with every unique date which occurs in (date_index). I am trying to get the code to return the index of every occurrence of i from date_unique in date_index.

```
for i in date_unique:
        month_index = [i for i in range(len(date_index)) if date_index[i] == (date_unique[0])]
        print(month_index)
```

for instance the above code for item 0 in date_unique returns output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

If I change the code to date_unique[1] I get output

```
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]
```

which is repeated 11 times as well (as per the number of elements in date_unique.
The output I am looking to get is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
continued for i in date_unique.
```

if you require input to test

```
month_index = ['032020', '032020', '032020', '032020', '032020', '032020', '032020', '032020', '032020', '032020', '032020', '032020', '032020', '032020', '032020', '032020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '042020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '052020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '062020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '072020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '082020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '092020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '102020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '112020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '122020', '012021', '012021', '012021', '012021', '012021', '012021', '012021', '012021', '012021', '012021']

date_unique = ['032020', '042020', '052020', '062020', '072020', '082020', '092020', '102020', '112020', '122020', '012021']
```

I hope my question is clear!
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate over `date_unique` and append the generated lists to a master list instead.

```py
all_indices = []
for j in date_unique:
        month_index = [i for i in range(len(date_index)) if date_index[i] == (date_unique[j])]
        all_indices.append(month_index)
```

A slightly shorter way would be

```py
all_indices = []
for date in date_unique:
        all_indices.append([i for i in range(len(date_index)) if date_index[i] == date])
```

Comment: Thank you Deepak! That has solved it, I appreciate your help!